# Webflux restcontroller unable to make an external api call

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I am using below code to test an external api call.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("risk-siphon")
public class KYCDataControllerDummy extends BaseController {
.....
    @Autowired
    KYCService service;
......    
    @GetMapping(value = "/kycDummy/api2/{version}/{customerId}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getKYCApiDetailsController(@PathVariable("customerId") String customerId,
                                                                   @PathVariable("version") String version) {
            logger.info("Get kyc siphon api dummy called for customer id:: " + customerId);
            Mono<KYCDetailsDataProvider.KycApiResponse> response = kycDetailsDataProvider.getKycDetails(customerId, version)
                    .doOnNext(dbres -> logger.info("Received api Details from MONO: {}", dbres));
            logger.info("Api response received kyc:: " + customerId);

            return
                    response.map(resp ->
                            ResponseEntity.ok(gson.toJson(resp))
                    );
    }

}
```

Service:

```
    public Mono getKycDetails(String customerId, String version) {
        logger.info("Api fetch call init for KYC Data for customerId::" + customerId);
        var responseTimeout = kycApiConfig.basic().timeout();
        logger.info("timeout::" + responseTimeout);

        String uri = config.getApiBaseUrl() + (String.format(KYC_API_PATH, version, customerId));
        return WebApiUtils.reactiveWebClientHTTPGet(uri, new HashMap(), responseTimeout, zestMoneyJWTProvider.getToken(), webClient)
                .exchangeToMono(this::exchangeKYCGetApiResponse)
                .transformDeferred(RetryOperator.of(this.defaultRetry));
    }
```

ApiUtils:

```
    public static WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> reactiveWebClientHTTPGet(String url, Map params,
                                                                           Duration responseTimeout, ZestMoneyJWTService.InternalServicesResponse token, WebClient webClient) {
        String bearerToken = token.accessToken();

        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(url)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token.tokenType() + StringUtils.SPACE + bearerToken)
                .httpRequest(clientHttpRequest -> {
                    HttpClientRequest reactorRequest = clientHttpRequest.getNativeRequest();
                    reactorRequest.responseTimeout(responseTimeout);
                });
    }
```

**Issue**
This code is expected to use reactive webclient and make api call to third party service. It runs fine on local and returns the external api response. Works fine in local docker as well. But when this is deployed to a EKS pod (test environment of release pipeline) it gets stuck and eventually throws a 504 gateway timeout error. While inspecting the logs from pod it seems like the thread is getting interrupted or some issue because of which the code is stuck at line

```
        return  webClient
                .get()
                .uri(url)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token.tokenType() + StringUtils.SPACE + bearerToken)
                .httpRequest(clientHttpRequest -> {
                    HttpClientRequest reactorRequest = clientHttpRequest.getNativeRequest();
                    reactorRequest.responseTimeout(responseTimeout);
                });
```

No logs beyond this line's execution prints.

logs from pod:

```
2023-10-18T13:11:26.412Z  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] c.z.r.provider.KYCDetailsDataProvider    : Api fetch call init for KYC Data for customerId::49fc59a5-0545-4630-9bbf-77223f8839e8
2023-10-18T13:11:26.412Z  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] c.z.r.provider.KYCDetailsDataProvider    : timeout::PT5S
2023-10-18T13:11:26.413Z  INFO 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] c.z.r.controller.KYCDataControllerDummy  : Api response received kyc:: 49fc59a5-0545-4630-9bbf-77223f8839e8
2023-10-18T13:11:26.490Z DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [42c4be51] HTTP GET kyc/api/v2/customers/49fc59a5-0545-4630-9bbf-77223f8839e8
2023-10-18T13:11:30.576Z DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [230852aa-187] HTTP GET "/risk-siphon/health"
2023-10-18T13:11:30.576Z DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [16d3cffe-188] HTTP GET "/risk-siphon/health"
2023-10-18T13:11:30.577Z  INFO 1 --- [oundedElastic-1] c.z.r.service.ServiceHealthIndicator     : Calling main service health v1 controller for risk-siphon
2023-10-18T13:11:30.577Z  INFO 1 --- [oundedElastic-5] c.z.r.service.ServiceHealthIndicator     : Calling main service health v1 controller for risk-siphon
2023-10-18T13:11:30.579Z DEBUG 1 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-2] .s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseEntityResultHandler : [16d3cffe-188] Using 'application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json' given [*/*] and supported [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json]
2023-10-18T13:11:30.579Z DEBUG 1 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-2] .s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseEntityResultHandler : [16d3cffe-188] 0..1 [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.SystemHealth]
2023-10-18T13:11:30.580Z DEBUG 1 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-2] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [16d3cffe-188] Encoding [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.SystemHealth@6605c4e2]
2023-10-18T13:11:30.581Z DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [16d3cffe-188] Completed 200 OK
202
```

Can someone help in understanding this issue please ?